# How to include twitter stream api in the python code to get access to realtime tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am using the python V2.75 and have installed all the twitter related packages for python using the command 'pip install twitter'. I have played around it and the api works fine. Now, I want to access the streaming api of the twitter for real time tweets. I have written the code as shown below

```
import twitter
twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=UserPassAuth('username', 'password'))
res = twitter_stream.statuses.filter(track='obama')
```

When i try to run the above code it throws an error "NameError: name 'UserPassAuth' is not defined". I could figure out that some packages have not been imported/missing. Could u please suggest some ways to get it working.

Comment: Try [Tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) for collecting and filtering tweets

Answer (score 1):

Read about [namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/). Class UserPassAuth is not defined in your global namespace, only 
twitter package is. Use absolute reference, as `twitter.UserPassAuth`:

```
 twitter_stream = twitter.TwitterStream(auth=twitter.UserPassAuth('username', 'password'))
```

It seams that you are following http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~astorer/twitter/twitter.html. Probably a typo (I doubt they meant to import `UserPassAuth`, since `TwitterStream` is referenced from module)